# How to Change a lot of TextBox.text of another thread than the UI thread (Using the same function)?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

My problem is to change a lot of TextBox.text of another thread than the UI thread.
Like this:

```
string bufferSerial;
.
.
.
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    bufferSerial += serialPort1.ReadLine();
    TextBox1.text = bufferSerial;
    TextBox2.text = bufferSerial;
    TextBox3.text = bufferSerial;
    TextBox4.text = bufferSerial;
    TextBox5.text = bufferSerial;
    TextBox6.text = bufferSerial;
    TextBox7.text = bufferSerial;
.
.
.
.
.
.
    TextBoxN.text = bufferSerial;
}
```

if I try to do this I have a ERROR: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

To change a single TextBox I could use this solution:

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

private void SetText(string text)
{
  // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
  // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
  // If these threads are different, it returns true.
  if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
  { 
    SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
    this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
  }
  else
  {
    this.textBox1.Text = text;
  }
}
```

and then to call the function like this:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  bufferSerial += serialPort1.ReadLine();
  SetText(bufferSerial);
}
```

But if I need to change a lot of BoxText I have to create one function for each of then?

Thank you for help!
Best regards.

Comment: Can you add the language you're using to the tags?

Answer (score 0):

No, create one method which changes *all* of the textboxes - and invoke that:

```
// We assume this will always be called from a non-UI thread...
private void HandleDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    bufferSerial += serialPort1.ReadLine();
    Action<string> d = SetAllTextBoxes;
    Invoke(d, bufferSerial);
}

private void SetAllTextBoxes(string text)
{
    textBox1.Text = text;
    textBox2.Text = text;
    textBox3.Text = text;
    textBox4.Text = text;
    ...
}
```

Ideally you'd have the textboxes in a collection so you could rewrite it as:

```
private void SetAllTextBoxes(string text)
{
    foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
    {
        textBox.Text = text;
    }
}
```